# Improving print quality from React app to dot matrix printer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, react-to-print

I am working on a React app where I use the "react-to-print" library to print content to a dot matrix printer. However, when I print from the React app, the text is printed in bold letters on the dot matrix printer, resulting in poor print quality. I have noticed that a Windows application(like ERP software), when used with the same dot matrix printer, produces clean and high-quality prints.

I have attempted to adjust various printer settings, such as DPI (dots per inch) and font weight, to reduce the boldness of the printed text. Unfortunately, these adjustments do not seem to have any effect on the print quality.

Printer Driver Updates: I have made sure that the dot matrix printer has the latest drivers installed, but this did not resolve the issue.

[issue print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5DDn.jpg)

Desired Outcome:
I am seeking assistance and advice from the community on how to achieve better print quality from the dot matrix printer when using the "react-to-print" library in my React app. My goal is to have the printed text appear clean and legible, similar to the output generated by the Windows application.

[Desired print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw0jT.jpg)

Additional Information:

Dot Matrix Printer: TVS MSP 270 classic plus
Operating System: Windows 11

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can't really help, but I could make a wild guess: Maybe the OS is able to send **plain character data** to the printer (like ASCII codes), which would be converted to dots inside the printer itself (using an internally stored font). I don't know if "normal" printers are even able to do that anymore. The browser can probably only send **rendered pixel** data (i.e. not text anymore), which need to be mapped to the printers dots, which will not exactly match the dot grid. -- I would research if browsers can send plain character data to a printer at all.

Comment: Any headway you have made on this? I really need this for a project I am working on